# How to find CDF of such complicated random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution

I have the following expression: $ P_o = \text{Pr}\left[Z<\gamma\right]$---(1)

where $Z = \sum_{m=1}^{M}X_m\cdot Y_m$

$X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential random variables having PDF $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma^2_1}e^{-x/\sigma^2_1}$ and $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sigma^2_2}e^{-y/\sigma^2_2}$ respectively.

I am trying to find the CDF of $Z$ but not getting it correctly.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Something seems missing: in $\sum_{m=1}^M XY$, no part of the summand depends on $m$, so it simplifies to just $M XY$.

Comment: Ok...I had edited the Question.

Comment: Start with the characteristic function of each $X_i Y_i$.

Comment: Ok... Apart from characteristic function, can we consider moment generating function....

Comment: Any help please.....

Comment: I am trying very hard but not getting it exactly.....Any help/suggestion please...

Comment: @paru: Really it looks difficult as stated.

First deriving pdf of $W=XY$ with known techinques you get

$$f_W(w)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{y}f_{XY}\left(\frac{w}{y},y\right)dy$$

At this point, considering that $X,Y$ are exponential I am not sure that there is an elementary form for $f_W$

Perhaps you can add more details on your question:

1. Do you have the result you have to show?

2. Sure that you are asked to find what you are asking

3. other detalis

Comment: Ok... Basically I am onto finding Outage Probability which is nothing but CDF of random variable....In this case the random variable is $Z$.